# Php gives an execution time exception with time limit set to 0

Tags: php, execution-time

I have a weird problem:

I have a method that needs a huge execution time(>60s), so I added a set_time_limit(0) in its class
This method has calls to other classes.

The problem is that I get an execution time exception. In one of the calling classes.

Could it be that I should add a set_time_limit in the other classes?

Comment: if PHP runs in safe mode the function set_time_limit will not help you.

Answer (score 0):

create a .htaccess file and insert the below code

```
//<IfModule mod_php5.c>  
//php_value post_max_size 5M  
//php_value upload_max_filesize 5M  
//php_value memory_limit 300M  
//php_value max_execution_time 259200  
//php_value max_input_time 259200 
//</IfModule>
```

I have added additional php values.. you can ignore that...please remove // before using the code

Hope this will solve your problem

Thanks